# Crystal report ignoring ODBC server

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, odbc

I'm trying to configure Crystal report to read the connection data from an ODBC, so it can read the required database given the system where it's installed.

However, the .rpt always connects to the server where it was created, ignoring the ODBC configuration (or, at least, the server name).

i've tried updating the connection and changing the ODBC, but still asks for the first server were it was connected.

is there any way to check if the connection is embed or to make the report read the whole connection from the ODBC?

*This happens with most of the reports i'm working on (about 100). 
I'm using Sap CR 13, and the reports were migrated from CR 8*

Thanks!

Comment: Try to update the connection after restarting the crystal reports.... sometimes crystal reports saves the previous connection.... try restarting the CR

Comment: Didn't work :(
it still uses the memorized connection.

Answer (score 0):

open CR without a report, go to `File`, `Log On or Off  Server` and it will open `Data Explorer` windows. Right there you can delete your old connection(right click on the connection and `Delete connection`) and leave the new one. Then, when you open the report, it  should have the new one.

Another thing you can try is going to `Database, Set Database Location...` and change the old routed table for the new one.

Comment: Where am I supposed to look to open CR without a report? this is the first time I see and use CR, so I'm a little lost.

Comment: just open the program, double click on CR's shortcut on your desktop or wherever you have it.

Comment: It didn't work :(
The reports still either connect directly to the wrong database or ask for the password of the wrong database.

Comment: I used to work with CR 11 and when I did a modification on those reports using CR 13, it prompted a windows saying that report was created in a different CR version and if I wanted to save it with my current version. I hit yes and that's it. Another thing you can try is going to Database, Set Database Location ... and change the old routed table for the new one.

Comment: My CR asks to upgrade the version of the report, but it keeps the stroed connections. I ended up giving the reports a DataTable with the data that it needs, it's a little slower than updating or changing the connection of the reports, but works better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Zar great that you find a solution